# How to stop comment spam on Django Zinnia?

Tags: django, zinnia

I can't seem to find an easy way to add a captcha to Zinnia's blog comments.  Surely other people have had this problem and already solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a captcha, but Zinnia will allow you to plug in a spam protection backend.

The documentation suggests [Akismet](https://github.com/Fantomas42/zinnia-spam-checker-akismet), [TypePad](https://github.com/Fantomas42/zinnia-spam-checker-akismet#using-typepad-antispam) or [Mollom](https://github.com/Fantomas42/zinnia-spam-checker-mollom)